# How to check if an javascript boolean element is present

Tags: javascript, node.js

At this point, I check if elements in an node.js object exist and get the value by doing:

```
if(req.body.name) item.name = req.body.name;
```

However, if I want to do the same for a boolean element, it is not working.
If the passed boolean is true, no problem, but if the passed boolean is false, the if statement fails, however, I need the value of it:

```
if(req.body.active) item.active = req.body.active; // works only if true
```

Is there a better way to check if an element in an object exists and to validate the boolean value of it?

Comment: `if (req.body && req.body.active !== undefined) { ... }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A few, you probably want in:

```
if("active" in req.body)
```

Comment: picked this one as solution, since it is the shortest and most clear one for me. Thanks though for all the quick answers!!

Comment: it looks like the shortest, but it does not reflect the value if it is not a boolean.

Comment: since at that point, I only need to check if the field is present or not, it is the correct way to do, right? Assigning the value happens afterwards, my sample code is just an example, not real used functionality...

Comment: @stijnpiron, yes the *in* operator checks if a certain property exist in an object or in its prototype chain

Answer (score 5):

> At this point, I check if elements in an node.js object exist and get the value by doing:
>
> if(req.body.name) item.name = req.body.name;

This will also "fail" if `req.body.name` is an empty string (put in quotation marks since an empty name is strange, but might not be an error).

I can think of the following:

- **in**: `if ('name' in req.body)`
- **hasOwnProperty**: `if (req.body.hasOwnProperty('name')`
- **typeof**: Either `if (typeof req.body.name === 'boolean')` or `if (typeof req.body.name !== 'undefined')`

However, all of them have advantages and disadvantages, which I want to name for the sake of completeness:

- `tyepof` fails if someone did something like `undefined = 'foo'` (which might not  be possible in modern browsers, however)
- `hasOwnProperty` fails if the attribute exists, but was inherited
- `in` does not (which might not be desired, depending on the use case)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a check for boolean and then evaluate the value.

```
item.active = typeof req.body.name === 'boolean' && req.body.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use this instead : req.body.hasOwnProperty('active')

It will check only the very existence of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For me the below code worked really well:

> if (req.body && typeof req.body.name === 'boolean')

It will work for all the cases where name is undefined or name is boolean or name is not boolean or body does not exists. It handles all the cases.